# Infinite product over primes' convergence with rearrangement

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation, infinite-product, absolute-convergence

If we know that $W_m(k)$ is multiplicative over $k$ (if $\gcd(k_1,k_2)=1$ then $W_m(k_1k_2)=W_m(k_1)W_m(k_2)$), and $W_m(k)=0$ if $p^2|k$, and that $|W_m(k)|\le c\cdot \frac{m}{k^{3/2}}$. So that the following series $$S(m):=\sum_{k\ge 1} W_m(k)$$
is absolute convergence. I have read that for the absolute convergence series, we may rearrange terms in the sum and obtain the same convergence. This means we can rearrange it and group as a product like this immediately?
$$S(m)=\prod_{\text{ prime }p}(1+W_m(p)).$$

Furthermore, if the above equals
$$\prod_{p|m}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{p-1}\right)\prod_{p\not| \text{ }m}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{(p-1)^2}\right)$$
how can we certain to multiply and rearrange terms in the product, like below? Or is it the consequence of being absolute convergence as well? I mean that the above becomes, if $2|m$, (by the book)
$$2\prod_{\substack{p|m\\p>2}}\dfrac{1+\dfrac{1}{p-1}}{1-\dfrac{1}{(p-1)^2}}\prod_{p>2}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{(p-1)^2}\right)$$

Comment: Let $Lppf(n)$ be the largest prime power factor of $n$. If $f(n)$ is multiplicative then $\prod_{p\le m} (1+\sum_{k,p^k\le m} f(p^k))=\sum_{n,Lppf(n)\le m}f(n)$. The absolute convergence of $\sum_n |f(n)|$ then implies that $\lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{n,Lppf(n)\le m}f(n)=\sum_n f(n)$.

Comment: Thank you @reuns. Did you mean $k\le m$ in the sum in the product you wrote?